# Don't understand Update Mode and watermark in Structured Streaming

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

I have following code, it outputs

```
number: 1, count: 1
number: 2, count: 1
number: 3, count: 2
number: 6, count: 2
number: 7, count: 1
```

I think `number: 6, count: 2` should not output, because the events are below water mark. But I don't understand why it outputs

```
import java.sql.Timestamp

import org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MemoryStream
import org.apache.spark.sql.{ForeachWriter, Row, SparkSession}

object UpdateModeWithWatermarkTest {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val spark: SparkSession = SparkSession.builder()
      .appName("UpdateModeWithWatermarkTest")
      .config("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions", 1)
      .master("local[2]").getOrCreate()

    import spark.implicits._


    val inputStream = new MemoryStream[(Timestamp, Int)](1, spark.sqlContext)
    val now = 5000L

    val aggregatedStream = inputStream.toDS().toDF("created", "number")
      .withWatermark("created", "1 second")
      .groupBy("number")
      .count()

    val query = aggregatedStream.writeStream.outputMode("update")
      .foreach(new ForeachWriter[Row] {
        override def open(partitionId: Long, epochId: Long): Boolean = true

        override def process(value: Row): Unit = {
          println(s"number: ${value.getInt(0)}, count: ${value.getLong(1)}")
        }

        override def close(errorOrNull: Throwable): Unit = {}
      }).start()

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
      override def run(): Unit = {
        inputStream.addData(
          (new Timestamp(now + 5000), 1),
          (new Timestamp(now + 5000), 2),
          (new Timestamp(now + 5000), 3),
          (new Timestamp(now + 5000), 3)
        )
        while (!query.isActive) {
          Thread.sleep(50)
        }
        Thread.sleep(10000)

        // At this point, the water mark is (now  + 5000) - 1 second = 9 seconds
        // when adding following two events: (new Timestamp(4000L), 6),  (new Timestamp(now), 6)
        // These two events are below water mark, so that they should be discarded, then should not output number: 6, count: 2
        inputStream.addData((new Timestamp(4000L), 6))
        inputStream.addData(
          (new Timestamp(now), 6),
          (new Timestamp(11000), 7)
        )
      }
    }).start()

    query.awaitTermination(45000)


  }

}
```

Comment: How did you fare on this Tom?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually not so hard.

**Watermark** allows late arriving data to be considered for inclusion against already computed results for a period of time using windows. Its premise is that it tracks to a point in time before which it is assumed no more late events are supposed to arrive, but if they do, they are discarded.

Excellent examples on https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#window-operations-on-event-time with nice diagrams to complement.

Comment: Thanks @thebluephantom. I analyze the result by reading the spark code. Please take a look at StateStoreSaveExec#doExecute,for the case(Update), the first thing it does it to discard evenst that are below the water mark(the baseIterator variable is created by discarding events that are below water mark)

Comment: From the manual on Append Mode, but I am wondering on Update Mode: withWatermark must be called on the same column as the timestamp column used in the aggregate. For example, df.withWatermark("time", "1 min").groupBy("time2").count() is invalid in Append output mode, as watermark is defined on a different column from the aggregation column. Your group by is on number.

Comment: Also this: Other aggregations Complete, Update Since no watermark is defined (only defined in other category), old aggregation state is not dropped. 

Append mode is not supported as aggregates can update thus violating the semantics of this mode.

Comment: Documentation a little vague.

Comment: Try aggr and update against created and see what happens.

Comment: ， I tried  aggr and update against created, and it works as expected now. The events that below the water mark are dropped before doing update. So, I will have to investigate the behavior when aggr and update against number as what I did in the question.

Comment: I confirmed from spark source code that water mark will take effect  only when the child plan's output contains water mark/event time column

Comment: I can't really follow why you think I was wrong now.

Comment: I never think you are wrong....... I just want to confirm from the source code's view.

Answer (score 1):

I think the official explanation about [output mode of structured streaming](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#output-modes) is already answered your question.

> Update mode - (Available since Spark 2.1.1) Only the rows in the Result Table that were updated since the last trigger will be outputted to the sink. More information to be added in future releases.

In your question, it means that the data arriving in 1 second will be update the filed 'count'